# extrafont: get the path to my installation of Ghostscript

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` and `extrafont`and following [Winston Chang's](https://github.com/wch/extrafont) tutorial `extrafont` on GitHub. My problem is that I cannot follow the step about embedding the fonts. In particular, I don't know the path to Ghostscript program on my computer (i.e "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.05/bin/gswin32c.exe").

The author says you should "adjust the path to match your installation of Ghostscript," see quote below

> First, if you are running Windows, you may need to tell it where the Ghostscript program is, for embedding fonts. (See Windows installation notes below.)
>
> ## Needed only on Windows - run once per R session
>
> ```
> # Adjust the path to match your installation of Ghostscript
> Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.05/bin/gswin32c.exe")
> As the name suggests, embed_fonts() will embed the fonts:
>
> embed_fonts("font_plot.pdf", outfile="font_plot_embed.pdf")
> embed_fonts("font_ggplot.pdf", outfile="font_ggplot_embed.pdf")
> # If outfile is not specified, it will overwrite the original file
> ```

The question is how do I find the path? I tried pasting it as it is, but that did not work.

Below is my code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library(extrafont)
font_import()
fonts()
loadfonts()  #everything works up to this point

Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.05/bin/gswin32c.exe") 

embed_fonts("font_plot.pdf", outfile="font_plot_embed.pdf")
embed_fonts("font_ggplot.pdf", outfile="font_ggplot_embed.pdf")



Poverty.f1<- ggplot(mydt, aes(Year , Pov1))
Poverty.f1 + geom_point(color = "blue") + my_theme() +
  ggtitle('Poverty Over Time') + 
  labs(x="Year", y= "Poverty Headcount Ratio at 1 Dollar a Day") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1985, 2012, 3)) 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm") 
ggsave("Fig_Poverty_f1.pdf")
```

The font I use in my_theme() is `Palatino Linotype` which works in the Rstudio viewer but not in the saved PDF file.

Comment: Any result when calling `Sys.which(c("gswin32c.exe", "gswin32.exe", "gswin64.exe", "gswin64c.exe"))`?

Comment: thank you. I tired it and it returned just the inputs gswin32c.exe gswin32.exe , gswin64.exe, gswin64c.exe . In each one, the "exe" had tow dots below it. I dont know what that means.